# How do I make a variable recognized in a string variable?

Tags: string, bash, variables, terminal, gnu

I have the following bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
Sunday="
   '$number'apples
   '$number'oranges"
Monday="
   '$number'bananas"
# ... you get my drift
Wednesday="
   '$number'bananas
   '$number'oranges"
# ... Until Saturday

range={1..3}

function GetDay()
{
    if [ $(date +%A) == "Sunday" ]; then Day=$Sunday
    elif [ $(date +%A) == "Monday" ]; then Day=$Monday
    elif [ $(date +%A) == "Tuesday" ]; then Day=$Tuesday
    elif [ $(date +%A) == "Wednesday" ]; then Day=$Wednesday
    elif [ $(date +%A) == "Thursday" ]; then Day=$Thurday
    elif [ $(date +%A) == "Friday" ]; then Day=$Friday
    elif [ $(date +%A) == "Saturday" ]; then Day=$Saturday
    fi
}

function CountFruits()
{
    for number in $range
    do
        GetDay
        for day in $Day
        do
            echo $day
            done
        done
}
```

Since its Wednesday I want it to output

```
1 bananas
1 oranges
2 bananas
2 oranges
3 bananas
3 oranges
```

How do I make this script work. It seems to be having troubles recognizing my range. It outputs

```
'' bananas
'' oranges
```

If I use the range directly with `for number in {1..3}` instead of the variable reference `for number in $range`

```
'' bananas
'' oranges
'' bananas
'' oranges
'' bananas
'' oranges
```

Comment: You'll be more likely to get a response if you create a [minimum viable concrete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your question instead of posting your entire script. Also, try pasting your code into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to get some automatic suggestions of fixes.

Comment: @jeremysprofile actually I had tried to simplify my script. The real script is different from this. Here I was trying to represent my script. Thanks for the suggestion and I will check out the website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate problem is that `$number` in each of your day variables is expanded *immediately*, so the value of `Sunday` is actually

```
'' apples
'' oranges
```

You would need to use single quotes on the *outside* to prevent expansion; the inner quotes are just regular characters.

However, this won't work, because the string `$number` inside the variable is just literal text as well; it won't be expanded with the current value of `$number` when `$Day` or `$day` expands.

What you need is a function:

```
dailyList () {
  # $1 - day of the week
  # $2 - a number
  case $1 in
    Sunday) fruits=(apples oranges) ;;
    Monday) fruits=(bananas) ;;
    # etc
  esac

  for f in "${fruits[@]}"; do
    printf '%d %s' "$2" "$f"
  done
}
```

Then, call that from your loop:

```
CountFruits () {
  for number in "$@"
  do
    dailyList "$(date +%A)" "$number"
  done
}

CountFruits {1..3}
```

Comment: I love the way you put the code. The only problem with this would be that I actually wanted the code to be like `fruits=('x' apples)`, in case I want to append the x in an array, like if `fruits=('x' apples and 'x' oranges)`. Like you said if I put quotes it will make `'x' apples and 'x' oranges'` text which was my problem. So it seems there is no way around not making the array string text without using quotes

Comment: That's different from what you asked for in the question. Would updating the call to `printf` be sufficient?